# How to refresh only one column in listview

Tags: c#, listview, refresh

Is there any way to refresh only one column of the listview?

`Listview1.Items.Refresh()` refreshes whole listview but I want to refresh only one column

Comment: I guess you aren't using WPF, do you?

Comment: Unfortunately I do

Comment: Why worry? Easy task with WPF if you are following the MVVM pattern. Can you show us some code? Are you using MVVM?

Comment: Sorry I cannot show you my code but I can try to explain what I'm doing here. I'm reading weight and dimension values (serial port) and I'm displaying those values in my listview ( in their own textboxes). I have tried PropertyChanged event but it does not work for some reason. And yes I am using mvvm.

Comment: Would be good to know why OnPropertyChanged wasn't working. But the approach is good. That's what I would have suggested. Can you maybe show just the listview xaml and the Property; just the important parts. I guess it's very simple when I see what you have tried.

Comment: I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface, propertychangedeventhandler and then notifypropertychanged metod. Rigth after I set the contents of label I put notifypropertychanged("weight"); but it does not do anything

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample for updating single properties in a ListView.

The window (contains a `ListView` and a `Button`).

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="{Binding First}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding Second}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"
            Content="Do something" />
</StackPanel>
```

The ViewModel for the window

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public RelayCommand DoSomethingCommand { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>
        {
            new ItemViewModel { First = "eins", Second = "zwei" },
            new ItemViewModel { First = "drei", Second = "vier" },
            new ItemViewModel { First = "fünf", Second = "sechs" }
        };

        DoSomethingCommand = new RelayCommand(OnDoSomething);
    }

    private void OnDoSomething()
    {
        Items.First().First = "sieben";
    }

    ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }

        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel for an item in the `ListView`

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    string _first;
    public string First
    {
        get
        {
            return _first;
        }

        set
        {
            _first = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("First");
        }
    }

    string _second;
    public string Second
    {
        get
        {
            return _second;
        }

        set
        {
            _second = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Second");
        }
    }
}
```

In the view you have `ListView` with two `TextBlock` for each item. When you press the button the property `First` of the first item will be updated. Maybe this sample code will help you figure out your problem. `RelayCommand` is my implementation for `ICommand`.